Consumer Client not able to connect to RabbitMQ server
I have written a c# consumer app to test my RabbitMQ service.  The solution works when running on the local machine and creates the queue however when running on a remote client, I get the following error.
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
I'm able to ping the server remotely.  If I put in a hostname that doesn't exist, I get a different error.
I'm using a test user account as I know the guest account wont work remotely and I've tested the test user account locally as well so I know it has permissions.
I've created and set up a rabbitmq.conf file with listeners.tcp.default = 5672 so the port should be fine.  My firewall isn't detecting any threats so I don't think it's blocking it.  When I check the log files, I can see a connection attempt when running the program locally but not when I run it remotely so I don't believe it's even getting to the authentication stage.
Please see my code below.
using System;
using System.Text;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
{
    UserName = "test",
    Password = "test",
    HostName = "HOST-01",
    Port = 5672,
    VirtualHost = "TestVH"
};

using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

using var channel = connection.CreateModel();

channel.QueueDeclare(
    queue: "letterbox",
    durable: false,
    exclusive: false,
    autoDelete: false,
    arguments: null);

var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    Console.WriteLine($"Message Received: {message}");
};

channel.BasicConsume(queue: "letterbox", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);

Console.WriteLine("Consumming has been started!");
Console.ReadKey();

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
